# Building vdproj with Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, visual-studio-2019

I have a C# project which I would like to automate using Jenkins
All C# projects work fine with MSBuild but I have 4 vdproj (Cabinet file projects) that I can't seem to get jenkins to create

I tried everything I could fine on google including using the DisableOutOfProcBuild file
I tried running it using the Developer command prompt

This is an example of a command line that doesn't work:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "exampleProject.vdproj" /build "Release" /project "exampleProjectName"
```

This is another try I made for the same project:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "solutionFile.sln" /build "Release" /project "exampleProject.vdproj"
```

Both cases just hang endlessly
Both cases **work** if I run them from a logged on session of simply running windows

The only thing that worked is when I changed the jenkins agent settings to Log on as my account instead of using the Local System account

I honestly have no idea how to fix this issue and would love some help!

Comment: `vdproj` is already obsoleted for a while, also `devenv.com` seems to be a `devenv.exe` (and having a IDE installed on build server is bad idea, IMO)